# Android libraries in ADT r14 in Eclipse - build error

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I've got Eclipse with two projects : Android library + main depending on the library project. From the new ADT r14 version it is no longer building correctly - it's showing following error on the console while auto-building:

```
ERROR: Unknown option '--extra-packages'
Android Asset Packaging Tool

Usage:
 aapt l[ist] [-v] [-a] file.{zip,jar,apk}
 List contents of Zip-compatible archive.
 [...]
```

Any ideas how to build this?

PS: I've tried cleaning / rebuilding etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks that the problem can be solved by manually downloading Android SDK tools + Platform-tools. Strange that it hasn't work automaticlly.

Comment: Looks like they caught the error; there's a new update for Package Tools in the SDK manager as of this morning.

Comment: ... Which didn't help although I didn't have time to restart Eclipse before leaving home. I'll have to check again this evening.

Comment: I meant "platform tools" in my first comment.

Comment: I have to do the following in the random combination: restart Eclipse, clean, refresh and at the end it worked.